# Loading a JSON data into a JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to load a `JSON` data into a `Jquery DataTable in MVC 4`.The following is the ActionResult in the Controller.

```
public ActionResult TimeZone()
    {
        BitlyDataStore json = new BitlyDataStore();
        var result = json.GetTimeZoneWiseScoreCard();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The corresponding output is a `JSON` data.The data is:

```
{"Scores":[{"Subject":"America/Los_Angeles","Count":421},
{"Subject":"","Count":636},{"Subject":"America/Phoenix","Count":40},
{"Subject":"America/Chicago","Count":686},
{"Subject":"America/Indianapolis","Count":50},
{"Subject":"Australia/NSW","Count":32},
{"Subject":"America/New_York","Count":903},
{"Subject":"America/Denver","Count":89},
{"Subject":"America/Port_of_Spain","Count":1},{"Subject":null,"Count":120}]}
```

How do we load this into a JQueryTable in its corresponding view?I have read through the documentation but couldn't understand how to pass it.I have tried passing through the Ajax code in documentation.The code is:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
            "ajax": {

                "url": "/Bitly/TimeZone/",
                "dataType": "json"
            }
```

Comment: I think your json data is not in proper format. Your `Scores` property is showing to have an array but I can't see a closing bracket for same!

Comment: i tested this JSON in JSONlint and it shows it is valid.

Comment: @HaseebMohamed  i think your json is object and datatable takes list or array see my answer.

Comment: i have checked your json data it  is valid can you provide punker/your code here? and here your not mentioned method in ajax .like....."type": "GET"/"POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your response is wrong the datatable takes list of data and your response is object there for you need to make list of yor data see bellow example.

```js
var datasource={"Scores":[{"Subject":"America/Los_Angeles","Count":421},{"Subject":"","Count":636},{"Subject":"America/Phoenix","Count":40},{"Subject":"America/Chicago","Count":686},{"Subject":"America/Indianapolis","Count":50},{"Subject":"Australia/NSW","Count":32},{"Subject":"America/New_York","Count":903},{"Subject":"America/Denver","Count":89},{"Subject":"America/Port_of_Spain","Count":1},{"Subject":null,"Count":120}]};

var dataitems=[];
$.each(datasource.Scores,function(i,item){
  var data=[];
  data.push(item.Subject);
  data.push(item.Count);
  dataitems.push(data);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataitems,
        columns: [
            { title: "Subject" },
            { title: "Count" }            
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example"></table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass the data other than specifying it explicitly in the code?I saw a code in the documentation by just specifying it in the `ajax` property.
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );`

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this it's working for me, whatever response your getting that object better should be data only not Scores like below ...(i dont have your code that is the reason i tried like this...

## object.txt

```
{
"data":[
    {"Subject":"America/Los_Angeles","Count":421},
    {"Subject":"","Count":636},
    {"Subject":"America/Phoenix","Count":40},
    {"Subject":"America/Chicago","Count":686},
    {"Subject":"America/Indianapolis","Count":50},
    {"Subject":"Australia/NSW","Count":32},
    {"Subject":"America/New_York","Count":903},
    {"Subject":"America/Denver","Count":89},
    {"Subject":"America/Port_of_Spain","Count":1},           
    {"Subject":null,"Count":120}
   ]
}
```

html is....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Routing with Route Provider First Application</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Count</th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Count</th>                     
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
//               "ajax": "obj.txt",
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "obj.txt",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    //"type": "GET"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "Subject"},
                    {"data": "Count"}
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this link also https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html 
for your case else follow https://datatables.net/examples/index 
for data tables...

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and the above mentioned methods.But these were not the answers that i wanted.My mentor found a solution and i am sharing it below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Bitly/TimeZone",
                "dataSrc": "Scores",

            },

            "columns": [
               { "data": "Subject" },
               { "data": "Count" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Where `dataSrc`and `data` are keywords of the datatable.Thanks for the help everyone!